# Is contextlib.closing() thread safe - Python

Tags: multithreading, python-3.x

I read about `with` statement in Python & understood that `with` statement will make sure to close resources on completion of job.

I m performing some DB operation & managing `connection` using with statement. But, I am not sure about thread safety.

```
with contextlib.closing(sqlite3.connect(self.dbName)) as connection:
    # Do Something
```

I also read about `threading` using `with` like

```
lock = threading.Lock()
with lock:
    #Do Something
```

I want to know whether `context.closing()` is able to handle multithreading or do I have to call `threading.Lock()` & do locking in addition to `context.closing()` like

```
lock = threading.Lock()
with lock:
    with contextlib.closing(sqlite3.connect(self.dbName)) as connection:
        # Do Something
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`contextlib.closing` has nothing to do with threads and thread locks apart from both being able to utilize the `with ...` syntax. It's essentially a convenience shorthand for:

```
try:
    connection = sqlite3.connect(self.dbName)
    # code within the `with` block
    connection.close()
except:
    connection.close()
```

So if you want whatever you're executing within a `contextlib.closing`, hmm, *context* to have an exclusive thread access, you'll have to use a `threading.Lock` (or `threading.RLock`) to ensure it.

Keep in mind that the order or nesting matters as:

```
with lock:
    with contextlib.closing(sqlite3.connect(self.dbName)) as connection:
        # Do Something
```

Ensures that only a single thread can obtain a connection at a time and *Do Something*, while:

```
with contextlib.closing(sqlite3.connect(self.dbName)) as connection:
    with lock:
        # Do Something
```

Means that any thread can get a connection, but only a single thread can *Do Something* at one time.

P.S. To avoid nesting hell, you can stack your with statements together as:

```
with lock, contextlib.closing(sqlite3.connect(self.dbName)) as connection:
    # Do Somehing
```

The first statement takes the precedent just as if you were nesting them.

Comment: Sorry for delay reply. It help to understand the things. Thank you :)